# Why is this audit "not an answer"?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed at [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/13713351) in the late answers queue.

I understand that the quality of this question is not perfect because the English is quite bad and it is not easy to understand. (I'm not a native speaker either)

But as the comment below the post states, the answer was flagged as "not an answer". Why? OP asked whether JDBCRDD uses HDFS or not and this is exactly, what the first sentence of the answer is about.

Of course I can't say if the answer is correct, but in my opinion, it is at least an answer to the question.

I've read this answer a few times and I don't understand how this is "not an answer". Can someone please clarify this for me or is this audit broken?

Comment: [That](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13641078) was a LQP review which deleted this post. Note that two people reviewed this as "Looks OK".

Comment: Because the reviewers in the LQPRQ are [doing it wrong](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: Once again, looks like the real issue a low-quality question. Maybe it's time for the review queues to take this into account, allowing users to take action on the *question* (the real source of the problem), rather than one of the answers.

Comment: I've never had a flag for Low Quality be approved. I've more or less stopped even trying to use that flag.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is just another example of reviewers going off on the belief that a short or terse answer is "not an answer". You can easily identify such cases by the seemingly non-sequitur "this should be a comment" review comments:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

This is why I almost never take review comments seriously. I think I'm just going to start deleting them wherever they were left inappropriately from now on. I used to reply to reviewers directly contesting their statements as a wake-up call, but that gets tiring after a while.

Note that, as mentioned, this answer was processed by the Low Quality Posts review queue, which often tags short answers such as this one as low quality (which is why reviewers are needed to vet them). But this answer is neither "very low quality" for the purposes of the flag of the same name, nor "not an answer".

Comment: Can mods temporarily ban people from reviewing in specific queues? If not, seems like it would be worth it just for this specific queue. Comments are easily ignored, but to have your "power" taken away from you - now that's a wake up call.

Comment: So you can basically get banned for failed audits, while the audit is actually wrong and your decision was the good one ?

Comment: @TimF yes. I got a ban for two days. // Shouldn't audits be really clear cases? I think if it's not 100% clear what to do (in my case, only 75% voted for deletion), a post should not be an audit. Audits are not meant to review the other reviewers. They are implemented to check if we are paying attention. And if the reviewers of a post want to take different actions, the post is not a good example for an audit in my opinion.

Comment: @FelixSFD I've got a 2 days ban too last week. Aside from the fact I don't find this pedagogic, it's frustrating to be banned while trying to help. Basically the system shows us a wrong answer while punishing us for our mistake, which is not even one. Testing us and showing us the (supposed) right way is fine, but why punishing a learner ?

Comment: @TimF The bans are important. But if the audit is wrong a ban is really frustrating

Comment: @FelixSFD it wasn't obvious from your question the audit had resulted in a ban. You should have said - anyway - the ban's lifted now.

Comment: @FelixSFD I forgot to mention it, because my intention was not complaining about the wrong audit when I wrote my post. I thought that I was wrong and don't understand why the answer is "not an answer". Thank you! :-)

Comment: I put an undelete vote on it.  Does that stop it from being an audit?

Comment: It *could*, however, use some expansion of the content hidden in that link. @FelixSFD How do you identify a "clear" case? Audits are chosen automatically by the system, iirc. I can't think of a programmatic way to do that, which is why there are a lot of meta questions of this variety.

Comment: @jpmc26 By the number of close-votes. In this example, 25% of the reviewers in the LQPRQ voted "Looks" ok. It would be a clear case, if 100% *recommend deletion*

Comment: @FelixSFD That's a good heuristic. On the other hand, I'm confident there are a lot of unanimous reviews where the reviewers decided the wrong thing.