# Low quality Posts: could we have another comment option?

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts

There is this very nice SE post on answers:

[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)

I'll link to the picture as well:

[image]

Please note the rotten apple on the right - that's not an answer, or is it?
No, it's a low-quality answer. So I get to review it in the LQP queue. There I can recommend to delete it and optionally add a comment.

Some of the available comments start with something like "This does not provide an answer to the question". So far, so good.

But which comment should I pick for

- [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39597480/5015207)? [OP needs to replace "{}", gets method to replace "{" as well as "}". If this is no rotten apple, then what is??]
- or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39469855/5015207)? [will crash according to OP's problem description]

I'd like to have another comment option. Something like this:

> "This does not answer the question. Please re-read carefully the information provided by OP."

I know I can add my own comment if I like, but then the comment will be lacking the "From Review".

**EDIT**

I'm well aware that my prototype of a canned comment needs some improvement. If we ever have one, it should contain "This does not answer the question", to be applied in cases where OP asked for an apple and really got an orange.

But Petter Friberg's comment links to another very interesting post (wish I had read it earlier) and this post in turn links to another by Manishearth with an even more interesting [answer by animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252218)

Meanwhile I think it was wrong to recommend deletion for the "rotten apple" type of question.

So especially the "wrong answer" button (with optional comment box) from animuson's post is what people like me need: we may know that an answer is an answer as long as the poster seems to attempt to tackle the problem. But sometimes it really hurts too much to click "Looks OK".

Comment: You can post *any* comment you like, no need to have that automated.  Do keep in mind that reminding a programmer that he can't read properly is excessively rarely appreciated.  So just don't.

Comment: @Hans Passant - well, yes, I think the choice of words leaves room for improvement. But the point is that if I post my comment from the review queue, it's not "From Review". It is not warning the answerer that I recommended to delete their post. So I think it would be better to have a nice polite comment telling the answerer that this is an answer which - still in my opinion - qualifies as low quality, period.

Comment: So just type "From Review" yourself, what the heck.  I personally find this all rather nonsensical, it only ever truly means one thing: "this post is not good enough to belong here".  Whatever bow you want to put on top of it is entirely up to you.  Something constructive that tells the user how to actually improve his post with explicit recommendations is always better.  Users not putting enough time in review or reviewing posts about a subject they know nothing about is a pretty chronic problem.  If you don't have time to help then just don't.

Comment: @Hans Passant - maybe I'll start faking "From Review" if I reach some much higher level of rep ;-) I may be a "user not putting enough time in review" in your eyes (enough is relative, and given my obvious difficulties in understanding the objective of some review queues it may be better this way), but please tell me: do you consider me as someone "reviewing posts about a subject they know nothing about"?

Comment: A rotten apple is still an apple.

Comment: This is related meta [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue), hence your comment on first post should be flagged : )

Comment: @Petter Friberg - exactly. I knew then that it did not fit and I'm leaving it presently only because this situation was what made me ask this question.

Comment: "But sometimes it really hurts too much to click 'Looks OK'." You'll just have to get used to it. A wrong answer is anything *but* "OK", but it just might be, quality-wise...

Comment: @BoltClock - I know. And I'm here, talking about it and intending to use the buttons the way they're meant to be used. But this "wrong answer" button would offer a way out not only for me but also for people who have access to the review queue but don't know that rotten apples are not to be deleted, doesn't matter why they don't know.

Comment: @0X0nosugar, you should just down vote, the idea of the que is not to delete incorrect or bad **answers**, but to clean up [non-answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39610293/5292302), you will need 20K of reputation to delete the answers.

Comment: @Petter Friberg - I understand that now. Thanks for pointing me to this link :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the comments (as well as your proposed text), the two posts in question appear to be a result of the answerer misinterpreting the question. That in itself doesn't make an answer low-quality. It makes it (often) incorrect.

You've left a non-sequitur "this should be a comment" review comment (which I just so happened to talk about [yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334776/why-is-this-audit-not-an-answer/334789#334789)) on the first post. That was a clear attempt at answering the question. It was neither critique nor a request for clarification. I don't see why you would recommend that the answer leave a comment on the question instead of posting an answer.

Your comment on the second post is specific enough to that answer that this sort of issue (technical inaccuracies) couldn't possibly be covered by a canned comment.

Neither of those two answers is particularly well-written, but that's a side issue. The fact that they come up in LQP is probably just down to that. An answer can be *both* incorrect and low quality, each for its own reason. You only get one vote per answer, though.

Comment: About the comment I left today: I was so unhappy with my options (no review comment or a bad review comment) that I wrote this question. But please explain to me: what makes an answer low quality if it's not enough that there will be either a runtime error or a completely different treatment of some String value ?

Comment: @0X0nosugar: There's nothing stopping someone from writing a very eloquent answer even if they misinterpret the question, or slip up or make the wrong assumptions in their code.

Comment: I'm beginning to think I misinterpreted the fruit picture :( Or rather, I think I  misunderstood the "because of its length and its content" part. It seems to be more a question of ideal proportions of text and code, not so much of "real" content. But thanks anyway for answering!

Comment: @0X0nosugar: "because of its length and its content" doesn't actually mean anything. Ignore it. It's a vague and usually counter-productive hint at the auto-flagging mechanism that pushes some posts into the queue, but the majority of posts are manually flagged for reasons that have little to do with either criterion.