# When an answer gets a NAA comment From Review, should it include justification?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, not-an-answer

At present, when an NAA comment "From Review" appears, it includes boilerplate stating that this is not an answer, and critiques or clarification requests should be comments.  In cases where the answer is clearly not either of these, should some justification (or even explanation) for the admonition be included?  If part of the purpose here is to improve the quality of the answers, then identifying what the actual issue would seem to be called for.

Comment: If a comment doesn't address the issue in the post it is not constructive. It doesn't matter if the comment comes from the boilerplate. The normal comment policy should apply: if you have something useful to say and are prepared to engage in a conversation, do so. If not, don't comment.

Comment: It would be nice if flags could be interpreted again the way they were originally envisioned, before the review queues were added.  It used to mean "Hey, there's something wrong here!  Whomever can do something about it, please have a look".  But it now needs to be all perfectly categorized and mean exactly what the flag says.  Like NAA, ugh.  Far too many times I see answers getting flagged that are troubled only because the question is far too vague to allow a decent answer.  So whack the question, not the answer, and solve two problems.

Answer (score 8):

I remember the days when people actually spoke their mind in comments.

Now, with review comments, it seems we can no longer rely on reviewers actually meaning what they "say" in the canned comments that they keep leaving in their wake, whether or not this was their intention.

The fact that you're now asking if a canned comment should include justification — and I can't think of any other way to include such a justification than *for the reviewer to add another, manual comment* in response to *another* comment (from you or someone else) requesting clarification of the original comment and potentially starting a drawn-out comment conversation *about the canned comment* — just goes to show how ridiculous things have become.

People, if you want to leave a comment on an answer you're reviewing, but the canned comment doesn't quite fit, the "add a comment" link is right there. You *can* enter a manual comment. And if you don't want to go to the trouble, the option of *not leaving a comment* is there, too. Last I checked, you are not forced to leave a comment on every answer you review in LQP. When in doubt, don't. Otherwise it just makes you sound stupid.

For everyone else, I refer you to [my answer on non-sequitur review comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334776/why-is-this-audit-not-an-answer/334789#334789). In short I agree with rene: just flag them as not constructive. If you really want to get a word in edgewise, just express disagreement with the canned comment and advise the reviewer to be more specific next time. More likely than not, the owner of the answer couldn't care less about the nuances of the review system.

Comment: "And if you don't want to go to the trouble, the option of not leaving a comment is there, too" I think the problem here is that reviewers *don't consciously review* anymore and just want the number to go down or up...

Comment: It's also possible to just edit the auto-comment if it's almost, but not quite, a good fit.

Comment: Fwiw, this is exactly why I was reluctant to add these in the first place: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117963/formal-adoption-of-pro-forma-comments-script-into-se-engine-proper/137363#137363 I do think they do more good than harm on balance, but there's no denying they get misused with some regularity. FWIW, the system automatically deletes these comments after a bit if there's no reply and the post isn't deleted.

Comment: @Braiam: I thought that was the case, but "No comment needed" *is the default option* - they could have just clicked right through the dialog to confirm the review without leaving an irrelevant comment. Unless they somehow managed to incorporate choosing a canned comment into their muscle memory...